# pe:layout: Align tabs to right

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

In the showcase example for http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/layout/tabbedLayout.jsf

tabs are centered right, I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried searching and applying ui-tabs styling and I can change size easily but not the tab alignment.

For example this did not work: [jQuery UI tabs aligned and sharing bar with a title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323579/jquery-ui-tabs-aligned-and-sharing-bar-with-a-title)

This seems to be the relevant css http://code.google.com/p/primefaces-extensions/source/browse/primefaces-extensions/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/layout/layout.css?r=1201

and pe-layout-tabbuttons is indeed present when I firebug the code but I can't figure out what to change.

I basically want this:

_________________|tab1|tab2|tab3|

instead of:
|tab1|tab2|tab3|_________________

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this CSS does the magic:

```
.pe-layout-tabbuttons {
    left: auto !important;
}
```

To see how to use CSS in JSF see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/).

Comment: That does not work with pe:layout and I do believe it reverses the order for normal tabs but thanks

Comment: @KarlKildén as the link you posted doesn't work I had to take a guess on which tabview element you were using. Looking at [this page](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/layout/examples/management.jsf) I came up with a new answer. So please see my updated answer. If this is again not what you were looking for, please add a link that works.

Comment: Hello @siebz0r and thanks again. Yes, obviously an oversight to only specify component in topic.

I fixed the link when I made my first commment but forgot to mention it. I tried your changes and it sorta worked all though not 100%.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/860312/Capture.PNG

Any idea why it won't go all the way to the right?

My code is just the barebone from the example link it's for a new function

Comment: Well then again tabs so far out would probably feel weird anyways. And the example i provided is consistent with your solution.

Still if you can understand why it can't go all the way to the right i'm still curious about it

Comment: @KarlKildénI don't know why it won't go all the way to the right. The example in the showcase shows the same effect.